Spring Boot @PutMapping consumes multipart/form-data not working
I have the following endpoint in Spring Boot (v2.7.15), using Java 11 :
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public SuggestionResponse updateSuggestion(@PathVariable("id") final Long suggestionId,
                                           @RequestParam("data") @NotEmpty final String data,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "files") final List<MultipartFile> filesForUpload,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "titles") final List<String> filesTitles,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "filesToDelete") final List<Long> filesToDelete)

This is working fine when my service is deployed on a Tomcat Server.
But when it is deployed on a Weblogic Server, the EXACTLY SAME request is failing with the message :
"message": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data"

The reason that I am using @RequestParam instead of @RequestPart is to serve some needs for front-end consumers.
I have verified that the consumers are sending Content-Type: multipart/form-data.
I am sharing here the curl that is failing on WebLogic (but is executed successfully on Tomcat) :
curl --location --request PUT 'https://host/test-api/suggestions/281' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Authorization: ••••••' \
--form 'data="{
   \"subject\":\"TEST SUB\",
   \"comments\":\"TEST COM\",
   \"rapporteurName\":\"TEST NAME\"
}"'

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

don't rely on what some consumers are saying - call your endpoint yourself and post the exact call that is failing here. You can extract the made call from postman by clicking the code icon and choosing to copy as curl

You should use @ModelAttribute except for @RequestParam. Both of these annotations are used to bind HTTP request parameters, but they have some minor differences. The @ModelAttribute is proper for sending data.
